# How do you calculate kw from kwh?

Tags: physics

A family spent \$235.25 in the month of February to heat their house.

a) Calculate the kilowatts of energy they consumed given that the price of electricity is \$0.09/kWh (kilowatt hour). Assume there are 28 days in February.

I came up with 672 kW, but I think that's wrong because 672 kW $\times$ \$0.09/kWh doesn't add up to \$235.25.

I think the problem I'm having here is that I'm not understanding what a kWh is. I know that a kWh is 1$\,$kW $\times$ 1$\,$h, but I don't know what that means. I mean, kWh is not the same as 1 kilowatt per hour, so what does kW $\cdot$ h mean?

Also, I don't think I understand what this problem wants. Do they want the kilowatts the family used in 28 days?

Comment: hmm, after 0.09 kw * h, it does a strange format automatically.

Comment: You aren't using the $ character correctly. Use one in front of the latex expression, and one after it.

Comment: How did you get 672? I suspect you weren't even using all the information available to you, since 672 happens to be the number of _hours_ in February (no matter how much electricity you use and what it costs).

Comment: The question should read: "Calculate the average power consumption (in kW) in February". 1 kW is the same as 1.36 HP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A kilowatt is not an amount of energy, it is a a *rate* of energy use.

For example, a particular heater might be using 2 kilowatts when it is turned on -- whenever it is turned on and for all the time it is turned on. If you turn it on for 3 hours you have to pay the utility company for $2\cdot 3=6$ kilowatt-hours of electricity. Of if you turn it on for half an hour you will have used $1$ kilowatt-hour.

That sounds like a somewhat strange sort of units to use, but it is traditionally used in electricity billing because for technical reasons the *rate* at which energy is used at a particular moment (measured in (kilo)watts) is easier to define and measure than the *total amount* of energy used over a period (measured in kilowatt-hours).

Additionally, the capacity of electricity production and distribution systems is naturally measured in how much energy it can handle per unit time -- i.e. power, measured in kilowatts or megawatts. This also has to do with the fact that (in contrast to, say fuel oil) it is difficult and prohibitively expensive to *store* electric energy in large amounts, so in practice it has to be produced at the power plant at the same time you're using it, and at the same *rate* you're using it.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to take the Watt for a unit of energy, [which it is not](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watt). Watts measure the *rate* of some energy conversion (something which is also called *power*). Energy is power $\times$ time, hence energy is measured in Watts $\times$ time, for example in kWh.

As a consequence, question a) *Calculate the kilowatts of energy they consumed* is nonsense.

Comment: It might mean _calculate their average energy consumption during all of Februrary_. (Which would be abour 3.9 kW).

Answer (score 0):

You would take 24 hrs x 28 days to equal the 672 hours per month. Take the $672 \times .09$ to equal $60.48.$  $235.25/60.48$ to equal 3.88 
3.89kw x 672 hrs is 2614.8 kWh x .09 per kWh is $235.26$.